# Caching Models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have a rails application, with a model that is a kind of repository.
The records stored in the DB for that model are (almost) never changed, but are read all the time. Also there is not a lot of them.
I would like to store these records in cache, in a generic way. 
I would like to do something like acts_as_cached, but here are the issue I have:

- I can not find a decent documentation for acts as cached (neither can I find it's repository)
- I don't want to use memcached, but something simpler (static variable, or something like that).

Do you have any idea of what gems I could use to do that ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am still looking for something similar to cache_flu but without memcached

Answer (score 1):

Could you store the data in a file and load it into a constant (as suggested on [Ruby on Rails: Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/8947c351681037d6)):

```
require "yaml"
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  MY_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "config", "my_config.yml")))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have started a gem called cache_me which can work with any cache_store

it's in Alpha mode but you can give a try and then open some pull request / Issues.

https://github.com/arunagw/cache_me

I will let you know when it's ready to use full mode.

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_cached was superseded by [cache_fu](http://github.com/defunkt/cache_fu).

Comment: Is there something similar to cache_fu that would not use memcache but something simpler ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in rails default cache or, as seems to be the most popular choice, use mem_cache_store which uses memcached.

```
#production.rb

config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, '127.0.0.1:11211', {:namespace => "production"}

#some_helper.rb

def get_some_data
  Rails.cache.fetch('some_reference'){Model.find_some_data}
end
```

See also:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Also, if you're using passenger you'll need to do this:

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
      Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).reset if Rails.cache.class == ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore
    else
      # No need to do anything.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use memcached, it is too heavy to put in place. I want something simple.

Comment: I guess SQL Caching is enhancing performances a lot in my case. I probably won't need something else, but it would be cool to have something like cache_flu that would work without memchached